# Applying the TOP keyword to an INTERSECTion in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a project that requires many INTERSECTions and uses a pretty large database, so I'd love to be able to apply TOP to my queries to make things not-so-slow.

Problem is, I know you can do something like (pseudocode-y but I hope it's understandable):

```
(SELECT TOP 50 * FROM A) INTERSECT (SELECT TOP 50 * FROM B); GO
```

BUT

can you do something along these lines in some way?

```
SELECT TOP 50 (SELECT * FROM A INTERSECT SELECT * FROM B); GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * from (SELECT * FROM A INTERSECT SELECT * FROM B) x; GO
```

Comment: Yeah this is the way to go. But remember that TOP without and ORDER BY means you have no way of knowing what rows you get and it can change from execution to execution.